# Excel VBA - can't find the Path

Tags: excel, vba, windows, path

So I have a simple Function and a part in my Code where I call that Function.

Basically it should check if the Path exists and then take that path to use it in my programm going along.

The Function:

```
Function GetFilePathIfExists(filePath As String) As String
    If Len(Dir(filePath)) > 0 Then
        GetFilePathIfExists = filePath
    Else
        GetFilePathIfExists = ""
    End If
End Function
```

The part where it runs:

```
Dim filePath1 As String
Dim filePath2 As String
Dim pathToCheck As String
Dim pathToTake As String

' Specify the file paths
filePath1 = "firstPath\invalid" 
filePath2 = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\TestFolder"

If GetFilePathIfExists(filePath1) <> "" Then
     Debug.Print "Found in A"
     pathToTake = filePath1
     
ElseIf GetFilePathIfExists(filePath2) <> "" Then
    Debug.Print "Found in B"
    pathToTake = filePath2
    
Else
    ' If neither file path is found, use the path of the active workbook
    pathToTake = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Debug.Print "Found in C"
End If
```

The Folder exists and is in the mentioned Path that filePath2 is expecting. However it always gives me the third case so the "Found in C" case eventhough it should stop at the "Found in B" Part of the code.

Can anyone spott the error? I've been trying for hours with different path that are used across the Programm that work 100% but this does not for some reason.

Comment: `filePath2 = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\TestFolder"` should have "\" in the end `filePath2 = "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\TestFolder\"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout Omg I feel so dumb right now.. thanks